# How do I disable validation of Javascript in <script> tags in JSPs ...in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, jsp

I'm using JSTL to generate a JavaScript object in a bit of inline script in a JSP, like this:

```
<script>
    var data = [
        <c:forEach items="${MyData}" var="Datum" varStatus="status">
        {
            foo: ${Datum.foo},
            bar: '${Datum.bar}'
        }<c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    ];
</script>
```

and Eclipse is totally unable to validate it. The HTML it generates is correct - so how do I make Eclipse stop trying to interpret/validate the JavaScript?

I've come across a number of similar questions here on SO, but none of them worked - including going to Preferences `->` Validation and checking the "Suspend all validators" box!

Comment: Aside: you should consider using a proper JSON encoder to produce this sort of structure rather than trying to do it yourself. Otherwise, characters like `'` in `Datum.bar` aren't going to get escaped to fit a JS string literal and you'll have script-injection security holes.

Comment: @bobince - You're totally right; I'll get there eventually. For now, I'm just trying to get the prototype together, and I'm actually using `bar: '${fn:replace(Datum.bar, "'", "\\'")}'` for exactly the problem you mentioned. The strings aren't from user input anyway...

Comment: Watch out for that last comma after `bar: ...`. It will crash IE.

Comment: @slebetman: see the `<c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>`? That omits the trailing comma. :)

Comment: @Bears: It omits the trailing comma for the array. But the objects within the array still has the comma. You wrote: `bar: '${Datum.bar}',` **<-- that's a trailing comma right there**

Comment: @slebetman: oh! Yes, you're totally right. Thanks. It's been a _long_ week. At any rate - my actual code doesn't insert that last comma.

Comment: Were you using MyEclipse?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still interested in a workaround;

Putting the code in a jsp file and including it withing the jsp file will prevent javascript validation.

```
<script><%@include file="data_include.jsp" %></script>
```

Another quick and dirty workaround:

```
<script>var data = [];</script>

<c:forEach items="${MyData}" var="Datum" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value="${'<script>'}" escapeXml="false"/>
        data.push({
            foo: ${Datum.foo},
            bar: '${Datum.bar}'
        });
    <c:out value="${'</script>'}" escapeXml="false"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Even if you do the serialization on the server side, Eclipse(Galileo) still gives validation errors for c:out and ${} within the script tag. I need to do something like the following, anyway:

```
<c:out value="${'<script>var data = ${jsonData};</script>'}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to escape the code with CDATA?

```
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
      ...
  //]]>
</script>
```

With or without `//`

Comment: Much as I wish that fixed things - no such luck.